# WCF Trace error: Configuration evaluation context not found

Tags: .net, wcf

I've set up a self-hosted service scenario where I'm programmatically setting up several service hosts. For each one of these hosts that I open, I see the following error in the trace log:

```
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning">
    <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.EvaluationContextNotFound.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
    <Description>Configuration evaluation context not found.</Description>
    <AppDomain>myprogram.exe</AppDomain>
</TraceRecord>
```

I've read that this is caused by using extensions that are not declared in the configuration file, and I am indeed using a custom behavior extension, but adding it to the .exe's configuration file did not have any effect:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="myext" type="mytype, myassembly" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    ....
</system.serviceModel>
```

Note that I'm not using this extension anywhere else in the configuration file, I'm adding it to the service host programmatically. I even set up a dummy behavior that used the extension just to see if it would resolve the issue, but it did not.

Why am I seeing this error in my log?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and found that I  had multiple identicle custom bindings in the ServiceReferences.clientconfig file.  I simply commented out the extras and all was good. (I am using Silverlight to call WCF services)

```
 <customBinding>
    <binding name="SecureTransportNoCredentialsEndpoint">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
    <!--<binding name="SecureTransportNoCredentialsEndpoint1">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="SecureTransportNoCredentialsEndpoint2">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="SecureTransportNoCredentialsEndpoint11">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="SecureTransportNoCredentialsEndpoint3">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="SecureTransportNoCredentialsEndpoint12">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>-->
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had WCF Interface with Classes that contained the string property "GCM" and then added a new Class definition called "GCM" . When I changed the Class name to "GCMObj" the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is, you have to manually create service with service name and other details under tag.

e.g.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
          <service name="WCF_NameSpace.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="behave">
              <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bind" contract="WCF_Trace_2.IService1"></endpoint>
          </service>
      </services>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you saying that if I create a service (in the configuration) that uses this extension (via a binding), the error will disappear?